# Skipping to next vowel and consonant in a string

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, while-loop, rotation

I completed an assignment that has the following instructions:

> Pseudocode and write a method that takes a spy's real name (e.g., "Felicia Torres") and creates a fake name with it by doing the following:
>
> Swapping the first and last name.
> Changing all of the vowels (a, e, i, o, or u) to the next vowel in 'aeiou', and all of the consonants (everything else besides the vowels) to the next consonant in the alphabet.

My solution:

```
@vowels = %w(a e i o u)
@consonants = ("a".."z").to_a - @vowels

def next_vowel(letter)
  i = 0
  while i < @vowels.length
    if @vowels[i] == "u"
        return @vowels[0]
    elsif @vowels[i] == letter
        return @vowels[i+1]
    end
    i += 1
  end
end


def next_consonant(letter)
  i = 0
  while i < (@consonants.length)
    if @consonants[i] == "z"
        return @consonants[0]
    elsif @consonants[i] == letter
        return @consonants[i + 1]
    end
    i += 1
  end
end


def alias_manager(name)
    name.downcase!
    first_name = name.split(" ")[0]
    last_name = name.split(" ")[1]
    

    alias_first_name = last_name.chars.map do |i|
        if @vowels.include?(i)
            next_vowel(i)
        elsif @consonants.include?(i)
            next_consonant(i)
        end
    end
    
    
    alias_last_name = first_name.chars.map do |i|
        if @vowels.include?(i)
            next_vowel(i)
        elsif @consonants.include?(i)
            next_consonant(i)
        end
    end
   alias_first_name.join.capitalize! + " " + alias_last_name.join.capitalize!
end
```

I'm trying to think of a much more succinct way of writing this. The 'while' loops don't seem like the most efficient method. I was thinking of using 'rotate' but not sure how I could replace the letter in the string. Also, is there a way to refactor the last to iterations for `first_name` and `last_name`? I'm basically writing the same thing twice for different variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to define `next_vowel` and `next_consonant`

```
    @vowels = %w(a e i o u)
    @consonants = ("a".."z").to_a - @vowels

    def next_vowel(letter)
      i = @vowels.index(letter)

      # Return the next vowel, using modulo for the last case (next of `u` is `a`)
      @vowels[(i + 1) % @vowels.length]

    end

    def next_consonant(letter)
      i = @consonants.index(letter)

      # Return the next vowel, using modulo for the last case (next of `z` is `b`)
      @consonants[(i + 1) % @consonants.length]

    end
```

Some test case:

```
2.3.3 :019 > next_vowel("a")
 => "e" 
2.3.3 :020 > next_vowel("e")
 => "i" 
2.3.3 :021 > next_vowel("u")
 => "a" 
2.3.3 :022 > next_consonant("t")
 => "v" 
2.3.3 :023 > next_consonant("z")
 => "b" 
2.3.3 :024 > next_consonant("d")
 => "f"
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your question might be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

That said - I'd recommend you look into these two methods:

- [`Array#rotate`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-rotate)
- [`String#tr`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-tr)

Which can simplify the code to something like this:

```
@vowels = %w( a e i o u )
@consonants = ('a'..'z').to_a - @vowels

def alias_manager(name)
  rotate_letters(name).split.reverse.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
end

def rotate_letters(name)
  name.downcase.tr(@vowels.join, @vowels.rotate.join).tr(@consonants.join, @consonants.rotate.join)
end
```

Comment: This is the best answer here so far.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW:

```
VOWELS = %w(a e i o u) | %w(a e i o u).map(&:upcase)
CONSONANTS = ((?a..?z).to_a | (?a..?z).map(&:upcase)) - VOWELS

def next_elem letter
  array = VOWELS.include?(letter) ? VOWELS : CONSONANTS
  array.each_cons(2) { |me, they| break they if me == letter }
end

"Felicia Torres".split(' ').reverse.map do |l|
  l.split('').map(&method(:next_elem))
end.map(&:join).join(' ')
#⇒ "Vussit Gimodoe"
```

Answer (score 0):

This method has been designed with efficiency in mind. The idea is to first create a hash that does the mapping of letters when encrypting individual words (using the form of [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that employs a hash for making substitutions). This should make encryption very fast, which would be particularly effective when there there are many strings to encrypt. As explained below, another benefit of using a hash is that it make it easy create a method that decrypts encrypted strings.

**Code**

```
def create_hash(arr)
puts "arr=#{arr}"
  (arr + [arr.first]).each_cons(2).with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h[k]=v }
end

v = %w(a e i o u)
c = ("a".."z").to_a - v
subs_hash = create_hash(v).
            merge(create_hash(v.map(&:upcase))).
            merge(create_hash(c)).
            merge(create_hash(c.map(&:upcase)))
  #=> {"a"=>"e", "e"=>"i", "i"=>"o", "o"=>"u", "u"=>"a",
  #    "A"=>"E", "E"=>"I", "I"=>"O", "O"=>"U", "U"=>"A",
  #    "b"=>"c", "c"=>"d", ..., "y"=>"z", "z"=>"b",
  #    "B"=>"C", "C"=>"D", ..., "Y"=>"Z", "Z"=>"B"} 

def code(str, subs_hash)
  str.split.reverse.map { |word| word.gsub(/./, subs_hash) }.join(' ')
end
```

**Examples**

```
code("Felicia Torres", h)
  #=> "Vussit Gimodoe"
code("eenie meanie", h)
  #=> "niepoi iipoi"
```

**Decrypt encrypted string**

One advantage of using a hash is that it makes writing a `decode` method very easy.

```
inverted_subs_hash = subs_hash.invert
  #=> {"e"=>"a", "i"=>"e", "o"=>"i", "u"=>"o", "a"=>"u",
  #    "E"=>"A", "I"=>"E", "O"=>"I", "U"=>"O", "A"=>"U",
  #    "c"=>"b", "d"=>"c",..., "z"=>"y", "b"=>"z",
  #    "C"=>"B", "D"=>"C",..., "Z"=>"Y", "B"=>"Z"}

def decode(str, inverted_subs_hash)
  code(str, inverted_subs_hash)
end

decode "Vussit Gimodoe", inverted_subs_hash
  #=> "Felicia Torres"
```

**Upper and lower case**

If the string is first downcased, remove

```
merge(create_hash(v.map(&:upcase))).
```

and

```
merge(create_hash(c.map(&:upcase)))
```

Doing so results in `decode(code(str)) != str` unless we assume the first letter of each word is capitalized and all other characters are lower case, in which case we could make `decode` return the original string by applying (as a final step) [String#capitalize](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize) to each decoded word.